# Cannot figure out where the error is: SetElement of Object Chart failed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a small chart that I am feeding via VBA which is not populating due to an error which I cannot fugure out how to solve.

Below is the code I am using:

```
Sub MyYOYTrendChart()
Dim DestinationWs As Worksheet
Dim chartsWs As Worksheet
Set chartsWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")
Set DestinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
 With chartsWs.ChartObjects("MYCHART").Chart
 .HasTitle = True
 .ChartTitle.Text = "My YOY Trends"
 .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd)
 .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
 .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
 .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Trend Current Year"""
 .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Master!$H$1"
 .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Trend Last Year"""
 .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Master!$H$3"
End With
End Sub
```

Any tip about how to correct and improve the above code?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is SetElement of Object Chart failed and the chart is not pupulated .

Comment: Which line throws the error? Side note, the `.SetElement` lines should not include parentheses: `.SetElement msoElementDataOutSideEnd`, and so forth.

Comment: What type of chart is it?

Comment: It's a 2 column chart and I also tried with  cht.SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd without parentheses but still not working. The fist line of code which throws the error is  cht.SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd

Comment: I guess `msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd` is not a valid option for your chart (it's for pie charts). Anyhow: As your chart already exists, I guess don't need to issue all the `SetElement`-statements.

Comment: You'd get the error if the chart doesn't currently have any data. Try moving the command after the lines that assign the data ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by correcting my code also as per your suggestions:

```
Sub MyYOYTrendChart()
Dim DestinationWs As Worksheet
Dim chartsWs As Worksheet
Set DestinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Set chartsWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = chartsWs.ChartObjects("MYCHART").Chart
With cht
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
 .HasTitle = True
 .ChartTitle.Text = "My YOY Trends"
  .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Master!$F$1"
 .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Trend Current Year"""
   .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Master!$F$3"
   .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Trend Last Year"""
   If .SeriesCollection.Count > 2 Then
.SeriesCollection(3).Delete
  End If
  .SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd
 .SetElement msoElementLegendRight
 .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart
End With
End Sub
```